# Selenium WebDriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Mozilla firefox 44.0.1 & java version 1.8  & selenium Version 2.48

I am using following [Web Page](https://uk.webuy.com/search/index.php?stext=*&section=&catid=956)

I need to select an item & press "I want to buy this item" button, which creates
1 item in basket area.  as soon as you add, basket on top right gets updated.
you will see:

> 1 item/s  View Basket

I am having problem locating this item , & I get "unable to locate element" error.
I have following line to locate the element:

```
String count = driver.findElement(By.id("buyBasketCount")).getText();
```

and I tried:

```
String count = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='buyBasketContent']/td[1]/span")).getText();
```

How do I access this element? I am trying to get value of one returned by variable count. but I get unable to locate element.

How do I access this element in the page?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Thread.sleep(enter some time in milliseconds)` but that is never a recommended way.

Rather use this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("buyBasketCount")));
String count = driver.findElement(By.id("buyBasketCount")).getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

Should use FluentWait. Something like the following:

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> ajaxWait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
            .withTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(75, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .ignoring(AssertionError.class);
final By by = By.id("buyBasketCount");
ajaxWait.until(new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
    public boolean apply(final WebDriver input) {
        return driver.findElements(by).size() > 0;
    }
});
String count =  driver.findElement(by).getText();
```

Answer (score -2):

try

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

before

```
String count = driver.findElement(By.id("buyBasketCount")).getText();
```

Or

```
String count = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='buyBasketContent']/td[1]/span")).getText();
```

Comment: Never use a Thread.sleep().  Different spec machines will need different wait times so this will cause intermittent failures.  Secondly if you have a fast machine that renders the element in 100ms you still sit there waiting for another 900ms for no reason.  Thread.sleep() slows your tests down and results in hour long test runs.  Just say NO! to Thread.sleep();

Comment: Good, I got it, the idea was to make him aware that the control not found because of the render and he has to wait, that set